# How to make the cart menu display the number of items added?

Tags: 7, commerce

How to make the cart menu display the number of items added?

Example If I added one item, the cart menu will display "one".

Module: [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Commerce Ajax Add to Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/dc_ajax_add_cart)**

> Using this module you can ajaxify the add to cart operation. The
>   updated cart will be displayed without page refresh and a popup
>   message will be shown after you add an item to cart. You can customize
>   the look of the blocks using its template files.

[image]